Extracting a special text from a given text in sql server
I have a text like this :
1XXXXXXXX/ZZZZZMR-A2
.L/TY7R7 
.R/DOCS HK1/P/IRQ/A11111111/IRQ/27AUG66/M/25SEP32/XXXXXXXX/ZZZZZ
.R/TKNE HK1 2222222222222/1
1QQQQQQ/WWWWWWMS-B4
.L/TY7HZ 
.R/DOCS HK1/P/IRN/N33333333/IRN/30SEP47/F/28AUG29/QQQQQQ/WWWWWW
.R/TKNE HK1 4444444444444/1

I would like to extract this information from the text above
first name: XXXXXXXX 
last name: ZZZZZMR

again:
first name: QQQQQQ
last name: WWWWWWMS

The first name and last name has this format :
1[firstname]/[lastname]

How can I do this?

Where is the data stored? Is this two records? One field or multiple? varchar or blob? Is it inside database at all?
